# Magento 2: After migration, Customer reindex is not working

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, indexing, data-migration, customer-grid

This is the issue I face on indexing from terminal.

```
column 'created_in' used in key specification without a key length, query was: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer_grid_flat`
```

[image]

Kindly help me to fix this.

Comment: Does the customer_grid_flat exist in your database? if not use the rest of the error to create it

Comment: @Dava customer_grid_flat doesn't exist. Tried the above query in phpmyadmin, throws 2 issues. 1-Unrecognized data type. (near "`FTI_AC9FBFAE9FBD3A0B02DBA986349612A6`" at position 2053)
 and 2- #1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'created_in' used in key specification without a key length

Comment: Your version of Mysql/MariaDB/Phpmyadmin are out of date they do not have the new data types you need to upgrade these so they can support FULLTEXT as a valid data type

Comment: Now, changed the datatype of 'created_in' from text to varchar(255) the query works fine. Then after indexing the customer_grid from the terminal, the same issue exists.

Comment: You will continue to have issues as there are quite a lot of new data types used in 2.3 as stated in my previous comment i would recommend upgrading your database software which should allow you to run without any issues

Comment: My mySQL version is 5.7, I think FULLTEXT supports here.

Comment: How are you running your commands? using a client or phpmyadmin

Comment: Using SSH but tried running the above query on the PHPMyAdmin it's fine. Please refer this full screenshot, only on indexing it throws issue. https://nimb.ws/9BurGK

Comment: when you try and create the customer_grid_flat table did you do in phpmyadmin

Comment: Yes, the customer_grid_flat table is created but when again reindexing from the terminal , the table is removed and the issue remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

check if created_in is removed from eav_attributes table itself; or created_in marked as is_filterable in customer_eav_attribute